# How to solve error `No such file or directory` in a container that is volume mounted

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I have 2 helm manifests - `Jobs`. One is supposed to create/generate a file with some configurations. The other is supposed to consume/use the generated file. `generate` works fine. But the other one -`load` - can't access the config file. Getting an error `No such file or directory`

Provided below are code snippets for the volumes. I think something is not right. 
I am using `StorageClass` object.

Thank you all

`generate.yml`

```
volumes:
        - name: {{ template "gluu.fullname" . }}-config
          persistentVolumeClaim: 
            claimName: {{ template "gluu.fullname" . }}-config-volume-claim
      containers:
        - name: {{ template "gluu.fullname" . }}-config-init
          image: gluufederation/config-init:3.1.6_02
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /opt/config-init/db/
              name: {{ template "gluu.fullname" . }}-config
              subPath: db
```

`load.yml`

```
volumes:
        - name: {{ template "gluu.fullname" . }}-config
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: {{ template "gluu.fullname" . }}-config-volume-claim
      containers:
        - name: {{ template "gluu.fullname" . }}-config-init-load
          image: gluufederation/config-init:3.1.6_03
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /opt/config-init/db
              name: {{ template "gluu.fullname" . }}-config
              subPath: db
```

Comment: Are both containers in the same pod? If not, are they running on the same host?

Comment: They are not on the same pod but they are on the same host

Answer (score 1):

Could be your Volume can't be mounted read-write by more than one pod. Try to mount the volume in the second pod

volumeMounts:

```
    readOnly: true
```

by default is readOnly: false